# How to display notification like any.do app using ionic platform android

Tags: ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dosM5.jpg)How to display notification like any.do using ionic-framework for [android](http://cdn.appstorm.net/android.appstorm.net/android/files/2013/10/todo-widgets.jpg) platform?

Using cordova plugins or android native code

Comment: Hi Balakrishna, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, post what you have tried and also try avoiding external links for images and use http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cordova plugins for the purpose.
See for example: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications